# Replacing letter-combinations in a string which is a column value in pandas data frame

Tags: string, pandas, replace, dataframe

I am currently replacing strings in a column of a dataframe. My data look the following:

```
df:
   Column
0   a,b,c
1   c,d,e
2   a,s,e
```

The data in `Column` are string, and I am replacing them with the following code

```
df['Column']=df.Column.str.replace('a,?', 'whatever')
```

This works perfectly, except for one 'substring' in the string, which is shown in the code below. When I try:

```
df['Column'] =df.Column.str.replace('type_IV_secretion_system_of_class_G_(ICE),?' , 'T4SSG,')
```

nothing happens. The 'substring' is not replaced and I get no error. I suspect it might have something to do with the brackets..Does somebody know what I have to do to replace my 'substring'? If you do it would be nice if you could also explain why my code does not work.

Comment: Does `df['Column'] =df.Column.str.replace('type_IV_secretion_system_of_class_G_\(ICE\),?' , 'T4SSG,')` work?

Comment: I didn't understand the relation between your data and your line that is supposed to replace the substring

Comment: @EdChum It worked! I guess it is some sort of escape sequence you used?

Comment: @NaderHisham The line that is to be replaced is equal to a b or c in abc. The dataframe should show the structure of the string in `column` and how I process it, whereas the substring in my code is a real data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brackets are part of the [regex](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) syntax if you're trying to match literal brackets you need to escape them:

```
df['Column'] =df.Column.str.replace('type_IV_secretion_system_of_class_G_\(ICE\),?' , 'T4SSG,')
```